# Why ' Exception in Application start method, java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ' occurs?

Tags: database, exception, javafx

When I tried to read some values from database and display it in a table in JavaFX, I got this exception. It was for the first time I see this exception, so I don't got any idea about why this exception occured. What will be reason for this exception ?

Comment: Supply code [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a complete stack trace and note which line number in the code corresponds to the error line reported in the stack trace.

Comment: @jewelsea Can you go to that link and help me ?

Comment: @jewelsea How to find the line number in the code that corresponds to the error ?